# Can't drop SQL Azure database - incorrect syntax near "

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm running some SQL against an Azure SQL server, trying to drop a database.

```
drop database "GEO-Dev-Scheduler";
```

When I run this command against my Azure SQL database in the cloud, I get the error `Incorrect syntax near '"'`.  When I run it against my `localdb` connection, it works fine.

According to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336259.aspx), Azure SQL does support the `DROP DATABASE` Transact-SQL command.  I need to be connected to the `master` database, which I am.  The `DROP DATABASE` statement has to be the only statement in the batch, which it is.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) gives some examples of how `DROP DATABASE` is used in Transact-SQL.  Interestingly, none of those examples enclose the database name in quotes.  My database name contains dashes, and when I tried removing the double quotes I got `Incorrect syntax near '-'`.  I also tried using single quotes as well as backticks just to thoroughly shotgun the problem.

Anyway, this SQL runs fine against `localdb` so I'm a bit skeptical there's really a syntax error.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

drop database [GEO-Dev-Scheduler];

Comment: To add a bit of information to this answer, the default characters for delimiting an object name in SQL Server are `[` and `]`. The ability to use `"` is an ISO compatibility thing, and can be enabled using `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` but it is off by default, and so it is off in Windows Azure SQL Database.